# Click <a> to show <ul>, but click other to hide the <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs, show-hide

I'd like to create a `<UL>` list like `<SELECT>` behavior but the `onclick` is `<A>` tag. anyone can solve the problem?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="grey-btn btn btn-mini" onclick="<?php echo $this->getJsModel(); ?>.showHideAction(<?php echo $i; ?>);">Action</a>
    <a class="grey-btn btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" onclick="<?php echo $this->getJsModel(); ?>.showHideAction(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="dropdown_action_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="dropdown_action_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none;">
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="<?php echo $this->getJsModel(); ?>.activeAddtocartSubmit(<?php echo $i; ?>, <?php echo $collection->getSize(); ?>, '<?php echo $_url; ?>', '<?php echo $this->getForm(); ?>');">Add to Cart</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
showHideAction : function(i){
    $('dropdown_action_'+i).toggle();
},
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the full HTML (ie: no PHP)

Comment: functionally it should be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GpW8M/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny getJsModel is class of javascript

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's correct but i wanted to klik other html outside the div, and it will trigger to hide. that's what i wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$('dropdown_action_'+i).toggle();
```

to

```
$('#dropdown_action_'+i).toggle(); // '#' is used to select element with specified id
```

Comment: $('dropdown_action_'+i) for get the id, $('#dropdown_action_'+i) i think for get the class or name.